# Calulate crc of an ethernet frames

Tags: package, tcl, crc, crc32

I want to caculate in a tcl script the CRC for this frame :

```
00000A00080000000A00090000004500002E0000000040117AC00000000000000000003F003F001AB6EB000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F1011
```

The expected CRC is 0x1652255A. I tried the following (found [here](http://code.activestate.com/lists/activetcl/249/)):

```
% set string \x00\x00\x0A\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x00\x09\x00\x00\x00\x45\x00\x00\x2E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x40\x11\x7A\xC0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x3F\x00\x3F\x00\x1A\xB6\xEB\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0A\x0B\x0C\
x0D\x0E\x0F\x10\x11
% package require crc32
1.3
% crc::crc32 -format %X $string
690CE0EE ;# not good

% set string 00000A00080000000A00090000004500002E0000000040117AC00000000000000000003F003F001AB6EB000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F1011
% set bin [binary format H* $string]
% crc::crc32 -format %X $bin
690CE0EE ;# same than previous one
```

There is something I don't understand with this proc, and I am not sure it is working correctly, because the result is always the same :

```
%  crc::crc32 -format %X foo
690CE0EE
%  crc::crc32 -format %X somethingdifferent
690CE0EE
```

If I go on [this online tool](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html), if find the expected result...

Is the problem coming from me or from the package ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing what you're seeing.

```
% set string \x00\x00\x0A\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x00\x09\x00\x00\x00\x45\x00\x00\x2E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x40\x11\x7A\xC0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x3F\x00\x3F\x00\x1A\xB6\xEB\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x0E\x0F\x10\x11


    E.@zÀ??¶ë



% package require crc32
1.3.1
% crc::crc32 -format %X $string
1652255A
```

Comment: Yes I did not put the return value of the "set string \x00\x00..." in my post but I have the same. The problem is with the last command which always return 690CE0EE in my case, whatever the input is. You have the result I am expecting actually, thank you for confirming that it should work.