# tcl : dict filter on a nested dictionnary

Tags: dictionary, tcl, proc

I have a dictionnary defined like this :

```
  dict set lag_in lagId    1                         
  dict set lag_in m1       port    "1/2"          
  dict set lag_in m1       ixPort  $ix_port(1)    
  dict set lag_in m2       port    "1/20"          
  dict set lag_in m2       ixPort  $ix_port(2)    
  dict set lag_in m3       port    "1/17"          
  dict set lag_in m3       ixPort  $ix_port(17)   
  dict set lag_in itf1     vlan    1
  dict set lag_in itf1     ip      10.0.0.1/24
  dict set lag_in itf1     vlan    20
  dict set lag_in itf1     ip      10.1.1.20/21
```

I want to define a proc that return a lag member depending on the port or the ixPort. First  attempt :

```
 proc getLagMember { dictionnary args } {  
    set opts(port)      ""
    getopt opts $args

    dict for { key val } $dictionnary {                                          
        if { [regexp {m[1-4]} $key] } {                                          
            if { [dict get $dictionnary $key port] == $opts(port) } {            
                return [dict filter $dictionnary key $key]
            }
        }   
    }   
 }
```

But this does not do what I want :

```
% getLagMember $lag_in -port "1/2"
m1 {port 1/2 ixPort {1 4 1}} ;# I am expecting port 1/2 ixPort {1 4 1}
```

So I tried to modifiy the `return` like this :

```
return [dict filter [dict filter $dictionnary key $key] key $key]
```

But I still don't have what I want. What am I doing wrong ? 
And is there a better way to achieve what I want ?

EDIT : Thanks to Glenn I come with this proc, but it does not work with -ixPort option

```
proc getLagMember { dictionnary args } {
   set opts(port) ""
   set opts(ixPort) ""
   getopt opts $args

   parray opts

   dict for { key val } $dictionnary {                                          
       if {[catch {dict get $val port} port] == 0 && $port eq $opts(port) || [catch {dict get $val ixPort} ixPort] == 0 && $ixPort eq $opts(ixPort)} {
           return $val                                               
       }
   }
}
```

Output with -port :

```
% getLagMember $lag_in -port 1/2
opts(ixPort) = 
opts(port)   = 1/1
port 1/1 ixPort {1 4 1}
```

Output with -ixPort

```
% getLagMember $lag_in -ixPort {1 4 1}
opts(ixPort) = 1 4 1
opts(port)   = 
ixPort {1 4 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
proc getLagMember { dictionnary args } {  
    array set opts {-port ""}
    array set opts $args

    dict for { key val } $dictionnary {                                          
        if {[catch {dict get $val port} port] == 0 && $port eq $opts(-port)} {
            return $val
        }   
    }   
}
```

---

Update: I don't get the same incorrect results you see:

```
tclsh << 'ENDSCRIPT'
    array set ix_port {1 {1 4 1} 2 2 17 17}
    dict set lag_in lagId    1                         
    dict set lag_in m1       port    "1/2"          
    dict set lag_in m1       ixPort  $ix_port(1)    
    dict set lag_in m2       port    "1/20"          
    dict set lag_in m2       ixPort  $ix_port(2)    
    dict set lag_in m3       port    "1/17"          
    dict set lag_in m3       ixPort  $ix_port(17)   
    dict set lag_in itf1     vlan    1
    dict set lag_in itf1     ip      10.0.0.1/24
    dict set lag_in itf1     vlan    20
    dict set lag_in itf1     ip      10.1.1.20/21

    proc checkAttribute {dict attr} {
        upvar 1 opts opts
        expr {[catch {dict get $dict $attr} value] == 0 && $value eq $opts(-$attr)}
    }

    proc getLagMember { dictionnary args } {  
        array set opts {-port "" -ixPort ""}
        array set opts $args

        dict for { key val } $dictionnary {                                          
            if {[checkAttribute $val port] || [checkAttribute $val ixPort]} {
                return $val
            }   
        }   
    }   

    puts [getLagMember $lag_in -port 1/2]
    puts [getLagMember $lag_in -ixPort {1 4 1}]
ENDSCRIPT
```

```
port 1/2 ixPort {1 4 1}
port 1/2 ixPort {1 4 1}
```

Say, you're not doing this, are you?

```
getLagMember $lag_in -ixPort 1 4 1
```

Comment: I just noticed that this does not work with the ixPort key. I just replaced the `if` by : `if {[catch {dict get $val ixPort} ixPort] == 0 && $ixPort eq $opts(ixPort)} {` and it returns `ixPort {1 4 1}` instead of `port 1/2 ixPort {1 4 1}` when I use option `-ixPort`

Comment: use `$opts(-ixPort)` *with* the hyphen

Comment: Even with the hyphen I don't have what I expect.

Comment: I don't have your `getopt` proc. Add `parray opts` after you call that and see what you have in there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I copied/pasted your script and have a different output. First line is all right `port 1/2 ixPort {1 4 1}`, but second line is `ixPort {1 4 1}`. It may be due to the fact I use tcl 8.4 ?

Comment: tcl8.4, probably. What output do you get when you `package require dict`?

Comment: It says 8.5.3
This is the tcl version that is needed by the package ?

Comment: No that's the version of the dict package. Sorry, my help ends here.

Comment: Anyway I have to deal with a weird custom version of tcl... Not the first time I have problems : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276120/calulate-crc-of-an-ethernet-frames/20279217?noredirect=1#20279217). And I can actually only use the -port option :)